# Prolog, New in Prolog and getting syntax error

Tags: prolog

I'm really new in Prolog (maybe few hours) and I'm getting these errors and warnings, most importantly please tell how to fix that error and where it comes from.

[My program](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6lxjxfrf7rqx1i/hwk11.pl)

This language is so vague.

Thank you.

```
   :- redefine_system_predicate(legalTime(T)).
       legalTime(T,[T|_]).
       legalTime(T,[_|S]) :- legalTime(T,S).

   :- redefine_system_predicate(subset(_,_)).
       subset([],_).
       subset([T|S],K) :- legalTime(T,K), subset(S,K).

   disjoint([],_).
   disjoint([T|S],K) :- not(legalTime(T,K)), disjoint(S,K).

   :- redefine_system_predicate(union(_,_,_)).
      union(L,K,M) :- append(L,K,M).

   :- redefine_system_predicate(intersection(_,_,_)).
       intersection([],_,[]).
       intersection([T|S],K,M) :-not(legalTime(X,K)), intersection(S,K,M).
       intersection([T|S],K,[X|M]) :- legalTime(T,K), intersection(S,K,M).

      difference([],_,[]).
      difference([T|S],K,M) :- legalTime(X,K), difference(S,K,M).
      difference([X|L],K,[X|M]) :- not(legalTime(X,K)), difference(L,K,M).

   :- redefine_system_predicate(legal_Schedule(X)).
      legal_Schedule(X,[X|_]).
      legal_Schedule(X,[_|S]) :- legal_Schedule(X,S).

Schedule(C, R, between(S, E)) :- Schedule(C, R, between(S, E)), between(S, E).
Schedule(C, R, between(S, E)) :- Schedule(C, R, between(S, E)), C depends on R.
Schedule(C, R, between(S, E)) :- Schedule(C, R, between (S, E)), duration(C)=<difference(E,S).
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Warning: c:/users/amir-i7/desktop/hwk11.pl:24:
        Singleton variables: [X]
ERROR: c:/users/amir-i7/desktop/hwk11.pl:28:8: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: c:/users/amir-i7/desktop/hwk11.pl:29:8: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: c:/users/amir-i7/desktop/hwk11.pl:30:8: Syntax error: Operator expected
% c:/Users/Amir-i7/Desktop/hwk11.pl compiled 0.02 sec, 16 clauses
```

Comment: Forgot '.' at the end of several lines before last?

Comment: You've studied Prolog for *maybe a few hours* and have concluded, *This language is so vague*? Would it not be more accurate to say, *My understanding of this language is still vague*? ;) And why the profuse use of `redefine_system_predicate` even on predicates that aren't system predicates to begin with (*e.g.*, `legalTime/1`)? There are some good books and online introductory tutorials. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of problems here.

1. Predicates must begin with a lowercase letter.

   I'm talking about `Schedule` on the last three lines, which are syntactically incorrect. You probably mean `schedule` here and this is probably the source of the syntax error that brought you here.
2. You don't need to warn about overwriting system predicates if your predicates are not system predicates.

   Prolog doesn't ship with `legalTime/1`, `legal_Schedule/1` so these directives don't do anything. Also, the predicates `union/3`, `intersection/3` and `subset/2` are not system predicates—if they are provided (as in [`library(lists)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists) with SWI) they aren't part of the global scope. So you should probably forget you ever saw this directive—even if you were using it correctly, it's a code smell.

   More to the point, these directives do not apply to the predicates that follow them. I think you've assumed that the "return value" or something doesn't "count" as part of the arity, but Prolog doesn't have "return values" in the sense that other languages do; the formal parameters encompass all of the inputs and outputs from the predicate. Your declarations for `subset/2`, `union/3` and `intersection/3` are correct, but you have the wrong arity for `legalTime` and `legal_Schedule` and because you used a non-anonymous variable in the latter you are getting a singleton variable warning.
3. Unbounded recursion in "`Schedule/3`*".

   Your rules follow this general shape:

   ```
   predicate(V1, V2... VN) :- predicate(V1, V2... VN), ...
   ```

   This is a meaningless infinite loop. I think you need to delete the part after the `:-` that repeats the head of the clause. If there's a reason you need to recur, you should probably do it after the tests you do, and not on exactly the same input.
4. There are no "functions" in Prolog.

   The statement `duration(C) =< difference(E, S)` isn't going to do what you want. Again, Prolog doesn't have return values, so this isn't going to magically send `E` and `S` through your `difference/3` predicate and substitute in the third argument here as a value. More to the point, Prolog simply doesn't evaluate terms like this. I bet you have a `duration/2` predicate somewhere else not included in your code sample and have the same expectation there. If this were to be rewritten as actual Prolog code, it would probably wind up looking something like this instead:

   ```
   duration(C, Duration),
   difference(E, S, Difference),
   Duration =< Difference
   ```

   I expect you'll be surprised by this. It's not Prolog but other languages that are vague. Prolog is actually simple and extremely well-defined when it comes to the shape of expressions and how they are evaluated. Other languages have a lot of special rules that you've internalized; Prolog is just going the other way, so it's confusing you. But it isn't vague. (And you may find you get better help if you avoid denigrating the thing you need help with—after all, the help is going to come from people who like it.)

Your largest problem here is that you expect Prolog to work like other programming languages. Probably you have a really dense class schedule and just haven't been able to give Prolog the attention it requires. There is no quick and easy remedy for this. You just need to crack open your copy of *Programming in Prolog* or *Art of Prolog* and reread those boring first chapters again. I promise, you will be surprised.

In the future, I would recommend that you include *all* of the code, not just the portion failing for you. I have lots more compile problems than the ones you asked about specifically because of this. When you don't really have a question other than "someone please make this work!" it is extremely hard to help without all of the code.

Comment: 'I am very good at long-winded explanations' - that's true!

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko I hate false advertising. :)